# What can I do to make this wave texture apply evenly along the segments?

Tags: texturing, node-editor, displacement

I am trying to create a necklace in Blender, and I wanted to create a smooth elegant segmented chain instead of the usual links. My plan was to use a bezier circle to make the shape and 'pose' of the chain, and I added a slight bevel to it and a small extrusion before converting the curve to mesh. Next I applied a wave texture with a displacement node and essentially this happened:

[image]

The wave texture doesn't apply evenly to each segment of the chain, instead making weird shapes such as the one at the bottom left of the curve (it also happened in a couple other places as well).
I would very much appreciate suggestions on how to fix this problem. Thanks and my apologies if there was something similar on this topic (as I'm sure there might've been, I'm not a Blender pro and I've only joined this website recently, so not much experience).

Comment: Plug a Mapping Node into the texture node. And plug a Texture Coordinate node into the Mapping Node. Then you can adjust the UV generation.  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/vector/mapping.html https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/render/shader_nodes/input/texture_coordinate.html

Comment: I understand what you're telling me, but I think I'm screwing it up somewhere.. EDIT: to expand on my comment, I've already tried adding Texture Coordinate and Mapping nodes and plugging the UV socket into vector of the Mapping node and I'm still having that same issue, though the distortions are sometimes in different places.